# How to review the answer with the link not found?

Tags: discussion

Today, I saw some guys try to edit some questions with the link not found? What should I do in this case? For example for the answer: [What are the side effects of disable a core module? (e.g. Mage_Rss / Mage_Log)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/560/what-are-the-side-effects-of-disable-a-core-module-e-g-mage-rss-mage-log/561#561)

Comment: we Just request to orignal author to remove that link , and reject that edit may orignal author change their post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I saw these kinds of edits as well, probably the same user. My approach:

- try to find the right link (often the content is still online but on a different URL). The archive.org wayback machine helps
- if no success, link to the cached version from archive.org directly
- if I would not find anything there as well, I'd remove the link. If the answer had no value without the link, delete it
- if it was an image, upload and embed the image instead of linking the external source

Comment: Thanks! :) It takes time if we try to review for this case.

Comment: Review takes time, yes ;)